# Using Digital Still camera as webcam

Tags: webcam, camera

I have an old Sony DSC P-200 camera. Can I use it as a webcam. If so, how?

Comment: For which OS? connection or type of computer? any more details?

Comment: I got it working on Ubuntu for a Canon EOS camera, but it's not easy askubuntu.com/a/1110036/114641

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My two cents are that for the amount of time and resources that you would have to put into accomplishing this, you could have bought a cheap little web cam.

Answer (score 0):

[Google says: Probably](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&rls=com.ubuntu:en-US:unofficial&hs=FrI&ei=HigHS-q7HpHIsAPX6-zACQ&sa=X&oi=spell&resnum=0&ct=result&cd=1&ved=0CBEQBSgA&q=Sony+DSC+P200+as+webcam&spell=1). You might start by watching [Sony's video tutorial](http://esupport.sony.com/US/perl/model-tutorials.pl?mdl=DSCP200). Have you tried following a tutorial but run into problems?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but probably not as you think you can, so for how you probably **WANT** to do it the answer will be no.

You *can* use the camera as a generic video source connected to a video capture card.  You know... you can connect your camera to a TV to be able to watch the movies you record with it.  Well, if you purchase a video capture card for your computer, you can connect the Cybershot to the video capture card the same way.  Then, you can just start whatever video chat software you were planning on using (AIM, Yahoo, Skype, OoVoo, etc) and tell that software to use the Video Capture Card you installed.  Don't go looking for the software to find the Cybershot as the source... you are using the Video Capture Card as the source.

Now... if you were expecting or hoping to be able to just plug some USB cable directly between the camera and the computer... you can do that to dump pictures or video, but that's it.  You cannot use the camera as a webcam that way.  It just isn't made for that.

In short, if you want to spend some more money for the Video Capture Card, then you can do it... however, considering a USB Webcam will cost about as much as a Video Capture Card, you are better off just buying some Logitech QuickCam instead of trying to get your CyberShot to suffice.