# How to use Canon Powershot A3100 IS digital camera as a Webcam in Windows 7 PC?

Tags: windows-7, skype, webcam, camera

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using Digital Still camera as webcam](https://superuser.com/questions/73326/using-digital-still-camera-as-webcam)

How to use Canon Powershot A3100 IS digital camera as a Webcam in Windows 7 PC?

Although I will purchase a new Webcam but for meantime I want to use my camera as a Webcam in Gmail chat and Skpye as a webcam. Is it possible?

Comment: I got it working on Ubuntu for an EOS camera, but it's not easy https://askubuntu.com/a/1110036/114641